# How do I pass a custom paramater into my modal class?

Tags: python, discord.py

So I am having a class which works perfectly fine and looks like this:

```
class Report_SurveyModal_NoRace(discord.ui.Modal, title='KRF1 Report'):
    was = discord.ui.TextInput(label='Describe what happened', style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph, max_length=1000)
    media = discord.ui.TextInput(label='Media', style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph, max_length=500, placeholder="blabalblablab", required=False)

    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        runde = ""
        await report_modal_submit_button(interaction, runde, self.was, self.media)
```

---

Now I wanted to modify it and need to feed a flag variable ( **steward_flag** which is either 1 or 0) through my class.

**My attempt:** I tried doing this by an **init** as I usually do with my custom written classes, like:

```
class Report_SurveyModal_NoRace(discord.ui.Modal, title='KRF1 Report'):
    def __init__(self, steward_flag):
        self.steward_flag = steward_flag
    was = discord.ui.TextInput(label='Describe what happened', style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph, max_length=1000)
    media = discord.ui.TextInput(label='Media', style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph, max_length=500, placeholder="blabalblablab", required=False)

    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        runde = ""
        await report_modal_submit_button(interaction, runde, self.was, self.media, self.steward_flag)
```

---

My Problem is that this seems to mess things up, because it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marcel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 427, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "d:\Daten\Programming\PYTHON\00_bots\07_krfbot\Bot\cogs\servicecenter.py", line 792, in callback
    await report_check_for_part_two(interaction, self.steward_flag)
  File "d:\Daten\Programming\PYTHON\00_bots\07_krfbot\Bot\cogs\servicecenter.py", line 658, in report_check_for_part_two
    await interaction.response.send_modal(Report_SurveyModal_NoRace(steward_flag))
  File "C:\Users\Marcel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\interactions.py", line 971, in send_modal
    params = interaction_response_params(InteractionResponseType.modal.value, modal.to_dict())
  File "C:\Users\Marcel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ui\modal.py", line 203, in to_dict
    'custom_id': self.custom_id,
AttributeError: 'Report_SurveyModal_NoRace' object has no attribute 'custom_id'
```

Im sure this error comes from the *"inside"* discord.ui.Modal - class, because there is nothing with "custom_id" in my Report_SurveyModal_NoRace class. I guess the *added* init messes it up..

I'm quite new to object oriented programming, so this might be an easy fix for one of you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `super().__init__()` to properly initialize the `discord.ui.Modal` you are inheriting from ([see the python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super))
Here, the [pycord documentation](https://guide.pycord.dev/interactions/ui-components/modal-dialogs#usage-syntax) does the same.

So your code would look like this.

```py
class Report_SurveyModal_NoRace(discord.ui.Modal, title='KRF1 Report'):
    def __init__(self, steward_flag):
        super().__init__()
        self.steward_flag = steward_flag
    was = discord.ui.TextInput(label='Describe what happened', style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph, max_length=1000)
    media = discord.ui.TextInput(label='Media', style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph, max_length=500, placeholder="blabalblablab", required=False)

    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        runde = ""
        await report_modal_submit_button(interaction, runde, self.was, self.media, self.steward_flag)
```

Comment: It nearly worked! I had to use "super().__init__()" instead of "super.__init__()".. maybe you can edit your answer so others won't run into the same error? Thanks a lot tho!